# Probability of a measurement under a continuous model

Tags: probability, measurement, density-function

I may be measuring the length of a stick. I then want to see what is the probability of one measurement under a model.

When using a continuous model, the probability of a single number is zero:

$$
    \mathbb P( \text{Length}=\text{length} \mid \text{Model}=\text{model} ) = 0 \>.
$$

What is right way to calculate the probability the measurement?
Should I calculate the probability of an interval?
If the precision of the ruler is 1 mm, should I use the $\text{length} \pm 0.5 \text{mm}$ interval, i.e.,

$$
    \mathbb P( \text{Length} - 0.5 \text{ mm} \leq \text{Length} \leq \text{length} + 0.5 \text{ mm} \mid \text{Model}=\text{model} ) \>?
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a continuous model, probabilities of single values are indeed always zero. Instead, one use the density of the probability distribution, which is uniquely defined almost everywhere, thus at the observed measurement. This leads to the statistical concept of likelihood, which defines a quantitative assessment of a given sample in a continuous model.

Comment: Also note that if you want to calculate the density function with the language you're using, it is the derivative of F(x), where F(x)=P(x<length|Model=model).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the probability density. I may have also some discrete random variables. Is it a good practice to mix f(x) with P(Y=y) in a probabilistic model?